# How to install 'ext-grpc' or 'grpc' on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, grpc, php-extension

I was trying to install **google/cloud-firestore** package in my Laravel 10 project. Then I was getting this error.

```
Problem 1
    - google/cloud-firestore is locked to version v1.31.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - google/cloud-firestore v1.31.0 requires ext-grpc * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension.
```

I was trying to install this extension using the **pecl** on my system but that didn't work as I expected. I also added the **extension=grpc.so** in my **php.ini** file as well.

Answer (score -4):

**Understanding the Error:**

This error indicates that the **google/cloud-firestore** package (v1.31.0 in your case) requires the **ext-grpc** PHP extension, which is missing from your system. The ext-grpc extension enables communication with gRPC (remote procedure call) servers, essential for using Google Cloud Firestore in your Laravel application.

**Resolving the Issue:**

1. **Verify PHP Version:**

> Ensure you're using PHP 7.2 or later, as ext-grpc is not available for older versions. You can check your PHP version by running php -v in your terminal.

2. **Install ext-grpc Extension:**

> If your system supports a package manager like apt, yum, or pecl, use the appropriate command to install the extension. Here are some examples:

```
        sudo apt install php8.1-grpc  # For Debian/Ubuntu (replace 8.1 with your PHP version)

        sudo yum install php-grpc      # For CentOS/RHEL

        pecl install grpc              # Using PECL
```

3. **Enable the Extension:**

   - Edit your PHP configuration file (**php.ini**). The exact location may vary depending on your system. You can usually find it in **/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini** or use **php --ini** to locate it.
   - In the **php.ini** file, search for the line **extension=grpc** (or **extension=php_grpc.dll** for older PHP versions). If it's commented out (preceded by a semicolon **;**), uncomment it by removing the semicolon.
   - Save the changes to **php.ini**.
4. **Restart PHP Server:**

   - If you're using a web server like Apache or Nginx, restart it to reflect the changes made in **php.ini**. The exact command might vary depending on your server setup.
   - or you can restart the PHP using **sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm**
5. **Verify Installation:**

   - Run **php -i | grep grpc** in your terminal. You should see output indicating the **grpc** extension is loaded.

By following these steps carefully, you should be able to resolve the **ext-grpc** missing error and successfully use the **google/cloud-firestore** package in your Laravel 10 application.

Comment: Obviously a ChatGPT response.

Comment: @Repox yes Gemini. But it took me one day to find the solution here and there, that's why I just want it here.

Comment: ChatGPT and other LLM generated content is [banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).